# How to read a query param from nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, query-string

I am having an issue reading query parameters from NuxtJS. Basically, I am copying the code from VueJS as is into Nuxt (with respect to adhering to Nuxt syntax). One thing which is not working is reading a query param in Nuxt.

When I say it's not working, it actually works in an asynchronous way. Here is an example.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="d of data" :key="d.id">
          <td>.......</td>
          <td @click="onSearchClick($event, d.searchTerm)"></td>
          <td>.......</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
methods: {
  getQueryParam() {
    let q = this.$route.query.q ? this.$route.query.q : null;
    console.log(q);
  },

  onSearchClick(event, searchTerm) {
    this.$router.push("/my-url?q=" + searchTerm);
    this.getQueryParam();
  },
}
```

During the first call, the console.log(q) value returns null (even when the query param is passed) and during the second call, the console.log(q) returns the query param (Even when I remove the query param during this call).

The same code is working in Vue.

I have tried adding async and await and still doing the same thing.

```js
methods: {
  async getQueryParam() {
    let q = await this.$route.query.q ? this.$route.query.q;
    console.log(q);
  }
}
```

[image: Table Date Image]

Is there anything that I am missing here?

Comment: When and how do you call `getQueryParam`? `async` is totally unrelated here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @kissu. My apologies for not mentioning it. I am totally new to Nuxt.

Basically, I have a table where I am using v-for to show the list of data. I am using click event on one of the columns and using this.$router.push(".....url?q=" ) and calling the getQueryParam method. I have edited the question.

Comment: It's supposed to be `this.$router.push` + you should probably use the query param as written in the Vue router documentation.

Comment: Here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location

Comment: Kindly ignore my typo. I am using it as this.$router.push and not this.$route.push. Updated it.

Comment: Tried awaiting the router push here?

Comment: Yes, I have tried adding await at router push. But not working. In fact, in Vue, I am using await at $router.push and it is working but not in Nuxt.

In Nuxt, when I add setTimeout for 2 seconds, I see the query param change but not when using async and await.

Comment: Mind sharing a [repro]?

Comment: @kissu To give you more context, I am using the query parameter in the same component. Is this a good practice or should I have to use a different component for the query param? 

This gives the list of records where I am displaying it in a table. When I click on the column it displays the same data as the table by filtering the query parameter which I have selected.

I have added how the table looks in the question

Comment: Can't say if it's a good practice, it's not a bad practice per-se at least. Regarding if it's feasible etc, yeah it's totally fine.